# Bootstrap input Group

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a checkbox with a label in a input-group. And when I have a long text in the label it looks like

[image]

What can I do, that the input-group will resize, that the text will fit into it?

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </span>
        <label type="text" class="form-control">asdf asd fas df sadf asdfsadfsdf sDASDF ASDFASDF ASDFasd asdfsadf asdf asdf asdf </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for help...

Comment: Paste the style, otherwise your question cannot be really addressed.

Comment: you better provide us live link where problem is

Comment: use the `textarea` instead of lable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do like this:

```css
.noFloat {
  float: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="checkbox">
            </span>
            <label type="text" class="form-control noFloat">asdf asd fas df sadf asdfsadfsdf sDASDF ASDFASDF ASDFasd asdfsadf asdf asdf asdf </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Close the "row" div

Remove *float* property from the label, adding the *noFloat* class

This is not the best solution but maybe fits what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the **row** div:

`<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <input type="checkbox">
                        </span>
                        <label type="text" class="form-control">asdf asd fas df sadf asdfsadfsdf sDASDF ASDFASDF ASDFasd asdfsadf asdf asdf asdf </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`

And you will get something like this:

[image]

Added JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27368/

Comment: even if i dont close the div i still get the proper result

Comment: Thats right, but when I close the row div, it is still not working !?!

Comment: maybe you have problems with the rest of your html, can you post the full code please?

Comment: nope. it wont work i guess , give the working snippet

Comment: Added the JSFiddle to my response, @user1861065

Answer (score 0):

You can either delete the line in the bootstrap.css inside the class .form-control

```
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;  <-- THIS ONE
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
       -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
          transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

or... add a class to this label:

asdf asd fas df sadf asdfsadfsdf sDASDF ASDFASDF ASDFasd asdfsadf asdf asdf asdf

```
.no-height-default {
 height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: this is also working, but I have to add this class not only to the label. I had to put it also in de div from the imput-group and in the span. Then it worked...

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is changing the form-control to form-control-static. like this

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon ">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                    </span>
                    <label class="form-control-static">asdf asd fas df sadf asdfsadfsdf sDASDF ASDFASDF ASDFasd asdfsadf asdf asdf asdf </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```